# Pop a message when user click on dropdown menu in configurable product?

Tags: javascript, magento, drop-down-menu

In a configurable product page, I am trying to display a message when the user chooses an 'out of stock' product from the dropdown menu (where there is the different size the product is available in).

The problem is I don't know where is the JS code that's used when click in the dropdown menu.

My dropdown menu looks like this:

```
Choose a size
38 - Out of stock
40
42
44
...
```

How can I do what I want ? I searched in js/varien/configurable.js but I'm not sure it's in here, I only saw:

```
this.settings.each(function(element){
        Event.observe(element, 'change', this.configure.bind(this))
    }.bind(this));
```

Can this code be useful ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have this project live? Can you provide the link to have a look.

Comment: It's not live yet, but it's like this one: http://www.bruno-saint-hilaire.com/index.php/veste-noire-homme-stretch-12652.html (it's in french, the dropdown is "Tailles disponibles")

Comment: You could just use jQuery, or other javascript libraries... on top of the existing implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this using following steps :

1) Go to below link and paste the code as suggested. This will give you simple associated product ID when you select a configurable option. http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-selected-simple-product-id-in-configurable-product-on-client-side/

2) Later write change event in jquery and get the select product Id from copied function from above url. Then send an ajax request using your simple jquery sending product Id as a parameter. In your controller check inventory of product. If that product is out of stock, send popup HTML in response and show it to user.